# Failed to load the "Magento_Msrp/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals" component

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

[image]

Magento 2 this error happen loading checkout page how to fix this

Comment: Is this error occur fresh magento installation or have you installed any third party module?

Comment: No i try  add custom tab in product view but i removed it but now this problem occur

Comment: Was this working before any time? if not, run these command and check again: 
      
php bin/magento setup:upgrade      
php bin/magento setup:di:compile      
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB

Comment: Working befor i tried these command

Comment: If this is working before, then revert your latest changes and check again. Checkout page does not load many time due to any error in the Magento_Checkout module or any third party module use/overwrite  the files of this module.

Comment: How can i do the  revert your latest changes im very new to the magento 2

Comment: If this is working before and this is new installation and you have not made any changes then it's should be worked now. Are you getting any other in console? Are you using Luma theme? if not then check with the Luma theme.

Comment: Where i want to changed theme product or some where else